# Can't place div on the same line as a vertical menu(other div)

Tags: html, css

I want to place div on the same line as the menu, but it always sits at the bottom of the menu, gets pushed by the other div. Postion: absolute on #slider id did not help.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eupayxu8/)

**HTML**

```
<div id=wrap>
<nav>
    <ul>
  <li class="var_nav"> 
    <div class="link_bg"></div>
    <div class="link_title">
      <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried to place display property, tried changing floats nothing helped and couldnt find something similar like this on the internet.
**CSS**

```
ul
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.var_nav
{

position:relative;
width:300px;
height:70px;
margin-bottom:5px;
background-color: #fff;
}
.link_bg
{
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 position:absolute;
 background:#373541;
 z-index:2;
}
.link_bg i
{
 position:relative;
}
.link_title
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
z-index:3;
color:#bc7c45;
}
.link_title:hover .icon
{
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
transform:rotate(360deg);
}
.var_nav:hover .link_bg
{
width:100%;
background:#373441;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.var_nav:hover a
{
 font-weight:bold;
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
 transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.icon
{
position:relative;
width:70px;
height:70px;
text-align:center;
color:#bc7c45;
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
ms-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
float:left;
}
.icon i{top:22px;position:relative;}
a{
display:block;
position:absolute;
float:left;
font-family:arial;
font-size: 18px;
color:#bc7c45;
text-decoration:none;
width:100%;
height:70px;
text-align:center;
}
span
{
margin-top:25px;
display:block;
}
#slider
{
   background:#373441;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 550px;
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: `nav {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get `#slider` next to nav?

Just add class like around_nav to nav tag:

```
.around_nav
{
  float: left;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eupayxu8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use flex:

```
#wrap {
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

**And remove all of the positioning properties from everywhere!**

https://jsfiddle.net/eupayxu8/2/